# Using templated function to read numbers from CSV file

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way of writing a single function that reads list of numbers (int or double) into a vector using a templated function?

Here is what I usually do:

```
template<class VecType>
vector<VecType> read_vector(const string& file){
    vector<VecType> vec;

    ifstream indata;
    indata.open(file);

    string line;    

    while (getline(indata, line)) {
        stringstream lineStream(line);
        string cell;
        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ',')) {
            vec.push_back(stod(cell));
        }        
    }

    indata.close();

    return vec;
}
```

My problem is with the `stoi` or `stod` part. How to handle this nicely here?

What I usually do, is to use `stod` and let the conversion happen automatically from `double` to `int` if the `VecType` is `int` for example. But there should be much better way to do this, right?

Comment: BTW, I'd appreciate a better way of reading `cells` from a line instead of `stringstream` which is slow

Comment: How about `VecType e; cellStream >> e; vec.push_back(e);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have specialized template:

```
template <class T> T from_string(const std::string&);

template <> int from_string<int>(const std::string& s) { return stoi(s); }
template <> double from_string<double>(const std::string& s)  { return stod(s); }
```

and use `vec.push_back(from_string<VecType>(cell));`

Comment: I'm getting `error: template-id ‘from_string<int>’ in declaration of primary template` and `error: ‘double’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter` what am I missing?

Comment: Typo from my part, `<>` should be empty.

Comment: This can also be extended to any input-streamable type by making the default specialization use `operator>>`.

Comment: This is indeed a very elegant way of handling the problem, and particularly with what @DanielH suggested.